# Google Chome with custom menu doesn't register clicks?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I have a custom menu that is built using standard LI and ULs.  It has one level of submenus.  When I click on these submenus in Google Chrome, the click event isn't fired.  This works in IE, but, does not in Chrome.

This problem cropped up recently, and I'm pretty sure all was good just a little while ago.

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
        #navMenu {
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
}
#navMenu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 9px;
}
#navMenu li {
    margin: 3px 2px 0;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#navMenu li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #E1DFD0 top left repeat-x;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 1.154em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: normal normal bold 0.985em/normal arial, sans-serif;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 6px 3px;
}
#navMenu li a {
    float: none;
}
#navMenu li a:hover, #navMenu li a.on{
    color: #FFF;
    background: #740404 top left repeat-x;
}

/*Sub-Menus*/
#navMenu li ul{
    margin: 0 0 0 -2px;    
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    visibility:hidden;

    position: absolute;
}

#navMenu li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    visibility:visible;
    width: 10em;
}

#navMenu li li{
    display: list-item;
    clear: both;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

#navMenu li li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 150px;
}

#navMenu li li a:hover{
    color:#fff; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="position:relative; top:0">
    <div id="navMenu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" >Menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Menu 2.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Menu 2.2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Menu 3.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Menu 3.2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Menu 4.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Menu 4.2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#navMenu li>a').click(function() {
   console.log("clicked a link");
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

There is also a fiddle for it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dslack/yLhxW/).

I'm at a loss to explain this, any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Works OK for me - Chrome 22.0.1229.94 on Windows 7...

Comment: the fiddle works fine for me on chrome/pc

Comment: If you need to differentiate between main nav clicks and inner nav clicks, take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SyTMQ/

Comment: That's weird. Your fiddle didn't work for me in Chrome at first, then I reloaded and it did work, I thought it might be the selector but that's not the issue. If you have any extensions in Chrome which inject content scripts, you might want to disable them or run chrome on a clean profile and then test it again.

Comment: I've disabled all my extensions, and the submenu clicks still don't register.  So strange, maybe I'll try a different PC...

Comment: Ok, so, it appears to be my Chrome install...  How strange.. Thanks!